# Brute force password breaker

Tags: python, pypdf

create a list of word strings by reading this file. Then loop over each word in this list, passing it to the decrypt() method. If this method returns the integer 0, the password was wrong and your program should continue to the next password. If decrypt() returns 1, then your program should break out of the loop and print the hacked password. You should try both the uppercase and lower-case form of each word.
This dictionary.txt file contains words in capital letters.

```
> import PyPDF2

pdfFile = open('reverse.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))
wrd = input('Please enter one word as a password: ')
pdfWriter.encrypt(wrd)
resultPdf = open('encryptedreverse.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(resultPdf)
resultPdf.close()
print(pdfReader.isEncrypted)

helloDict = open('dictionary.txt')
helloDictCont = helloDict.read().splitlines()

liDict = []
for word in helloDictCont:
    liDict.extend(word.split())

PdfFile2 = open('encryptedreverse.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PdfFile2)
print(pdfReader2.isEncrypted)

for word in liDict:
    if pdfReader2.decrypt(word) == 1:
        break
        print(word)
    elif pdfReader2.decrypt(word.lower()) == 1:
        break
        print(word)
```

After a few minutes processing ends and I neither get a password printed nor the pdf file is decrypted. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: first break, then print word -> unreachable code? Also, you should add a print that indicates none of the words was correct. (Easier to debug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFile = open('reverse.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))
wrd = input('Please enter one word as a password: ')
pdfWriter.encrypt(wrd)
resultPdf = open('encryptedreverse.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(resultPdf)
resultPdf.close()
print(pdfReader.isEncrypted)

helloDict = open('t.txt')
helloDictCont = helloDict.read().splitlines()

liDict = []
for word in helloDictCont:
    liDict.extend(word.split())

PdfFile2 = open('encryptedreverse.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PdfFile2)
print(pdfReader2.isEncrypted)

for word in liDict:
    if pdfReader2.decrypt(word) == 1:
        print('The correct PWD as upper case: ' + word)
        break
    elif pdfReader2.decrypt(word.lower()) == 1:
        print('The correct PWD as lower case: ' + word)
        break
    else:
        print('PWD is not correct: ' + word)
```

Comment: That would print all incorrect passwords. Is that intentional?

Comment: That is only for debug purpose

Comment: The goal is to print only the correct password. Still don't understand why it doesn't work. I don't want to print all the words from the dictionary.

Comment: Okay, then delete the else statement in my code. I believe that will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution:

```
'''
Brute-Force PDF Password Breaker
Say you have an encrypted PDF that you have forgotten the password to, 
but you remember it was a single English word. Trying to guess your forgot-
ten password is quite a boring task. Instead you can write a program that 
will decrypt the PDF by trying every possible English word until it finds one 
that works. This is called a brute-force password attack. Download the text file 
dictionary.txt from https://nostarch.com/automatestuff2/. This dictionary file 
contains over 44,000 English words with one word per line.
Using the file-reading skills you learned in Chapter 9, create a list of 
word strings by reading this file. Then loop over each word in this list, pass -
ing it to the decrypt() method. If this method returns the integer 0, the pass-
word was wrong and your program should continue to the next password. 
If decrypt() returns 1, then your program should break out of the loop and 
print the hacked password. You should try both the uppercase and lower-
case form of each word. (On my laptop, going through all 88,000 uppercase 
and lowercase words from the dictionary file takes a couple of minutes. This 
is why you shouldn’t use a simple English word for your passwords.)
'''
import PyPDF2
import time
import os
import sys


def decrypt():
    ok = False
    print(f'Working... {time.asctime()}')
    start = time.time()
    passwords = open(dictionary).read().split('\n')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
    if pdfReader.isEncrypted:
        for password in passwords:
            if pdfReader.decrypt(password) or pdfReader.decrypt(password.lower()):
                print(f'Password: {password}')
                ok = True
                break
        end = time.time()
        hours = int((end - start) / 3600)
        minutes = int((end - start) / 60)
        secondes = int(end - start - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60))
        if ok:
            print(f'Has been decrypted in {hours}H:{minutes}M:{secondes}S!')
        else:
            print(f'{pdf} hasn\'t been decrypted... Maybe need a better dictionary?')
    else:
        print(f'{pdf} isn\'t encrypted')


if len(sys.argv) == 3:    
    dictionary, pdf = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    if os.path.isfile(dictionary) and dictionary.endswith('.txt'):
        if os.path.isfile(pdf) and pdf.endswith('.pdf'):
            decrypt()
        else:
            print('Invalid path to pdf or pdf file')
    else:
        print('Invalid path to dictionary or dictionary file')
else:
    print('Please enter arguments as example:\
        \ndictionaryName.txt pdfName.pdf')
```

Comment: ...but note that asking for code review is off-topic here. You might have better luck on [codereview.se].